# Symfony 1.4- Doctrine Soft Delete Functionality

Tags: php, symfony-1.4, doctrine-1.2, soft-delete

I want to override "soft delete" functionality in symfony 1.4-Doctrine ORM.

I got the file path:
lib/vendor/symfony/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/vendor/doctrine/Doctrine/Template/Listener/SoftDelete.php

But i am not able to override the same file to change the functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got the solution.

Override

> lib/vendor/symfony/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/vendor/doctrine/Doctrine/Template/Listener/SoftDelete.php

to

> path_to_project/lib/listener/SoftDelete.php

It works for me.